# Fiddler-like host and port remapping using nginx on Linux

Tags: linux, nginx, reverse-proxy, hosts

I am trying to set up [host and port remapping on Linux using nginx as a reverse proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10729076/238421).

So far, I've got a working [ghetto hack solution](https://serverfault.com/a/286835/35332) using [the `if` directive](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#using-if), which is [evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

Is there a better solution without using `if`?

**What I have tried - nginx configuration**

*/etc/nginx/nginx.conf* (or some /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf file):

```
server {
    listen 3000;
    server_name dev.example.com test.example.com prod.example.com
    location / {
        if ($http_host ~ dev.example.com) {
            proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:13000;
        }
        if ($http_host ~ test.example.com) {
            proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:23000;
        }
        if ($http_host ~ prod.example.com) {
            proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:33000;
        }
    }
}
```

*/etc/hosts*:

```
127.0.0.1 dev.example.com
127.0.0.1 test.example.com
127.0.0.1 prod.example.com
```

**What I would like to do - Fiddler HOSTS configuration**

For those familiar with Fiddler, I am trying to emulate this [HOSTS configuration](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/KnowledgeBase/HOSTS):

```
localhost:13000 dev.example.com:3000
localhost:23000 test.example.com:3000
localhost:33000 prod.example.com:3000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use separate `server` blocks:

```
server {
    server_name dev.example.com;
    listen 3000;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:13000;
}

server {
    server_name test.example.com;
    listen 3000;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:23000;
}
```

And another one for `prod.example.com`.

If these site configurations contain common elements, include them in another file and use the `include` directive to apply those elements to each virtual server.

Comment: I had to increase `server_names_hash_bucket_size` to 128 (possibly because my actual server names are a bit longer).

Answer (score 1):

Leverage the [map](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) module:

`http` context:

```
map $http_host $proxy_target {
    "dev.example.com" "127.0.0.1:13000";
    "test.example.com" "127.0.0.1:23000";
    "prod.example.com" "127.0.0.1:33000";
}
```

`server` context:

```
proxy_pass $proxy_target;
```

Also, you could try to only differentiate the port, and use something like

```
proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:$proxy_port;
```

but I'm not sure if joining like this will work.