# How to set proxy_pass conditionally based on $host value?

Tags: nginx

I am trying to set `proxy_pass` based on $host value, I tried this:

```
location /api/v1/ {
    if ($host = .*\.npreprod.company.com)
    {
            proxy_pass https://frontend-api.preprod.company.com/api/v1/;
    }
}
```

however, I got the error

> nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/nuxtjs.conf:45

so, what's the proper way to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nginx location regex doesn't work with proxy pass](https://serverfault.com/questions/649151/nginx-location-regex-doesnt-work-with-proxy-pass)

Comment: I don't think this is the correct duplicate. I'm pretty sure we already have one or more questions addressing the [if is evil problem](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/), but I can't find one right now.

Comment: @AlexD I am not sure how would I apply the answer at that question in my case

Comment: @GeraldSchneider this one describes how to match a hostname better https://serverfault.com/questions/286828/nginx-matching-server-host-name-in-location-directive

Comment: Rather than testing the value of `$host` inside the `server` block, you could create a separate `server` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html).

Comment: Thanks@AlexD , yes, that's what I ended doing, it worked well.